# Unbiasedness and consistency

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, bias, unbiased-estimator, consistency

Assume the simple regression model satisfying all Gauss-Markov assumptions.

Somebody suggests the estimator

[image]

Why may someone consider such an estimator?

Why will this estimator be consistent? Why is it biased?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users. 
Please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've thought of & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.  If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've thought of so far.